# bower npm -- get error 'bower MODULE_NOT_FOUND Cannot find module 'form-data' every time

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I get bower MODULE_NOT_FOUND      Cannot find module 'form-data' 
every time I try to use the commands (bower init or bower install) ,

I also have tried to use npm install --save form-data 
also npm install -g 
and many other solution but nothing was useful

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I am on windows XP with npm ver 2.14.7 and git ver 2.6.2. And the solution you gave below is not working for me.

Comment: this solution only works on mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
export NODE_PATH=${PWD}/node_modules
```

I used this command to solve the problem